# Best data representation for char-based text analysis

Tags: deep-learning, text-mining

I could not find on the internet which is the best/standard way to process strings as sequences of characters in Deep Learning algorithm (es. GAN,CNN, etc.).

For example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00440) they are generating plausible passwords using a GAN. 
I tired to do something similar for another project, but the most reasonable way to process character sequences that I could think of was to encode characters to one-hot vectors. 
But it doesn't seem an optimal way to face the problem, as you end up with huge sparse matrices which are heavy to process and they are much more complex in dimensionality than a string.

Processing chars as integers doesn't seem a good approach either as it adds a sequentiality that is not related to the study case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first idea is the way to go. 
In text processing, documents are usually one-hot-coded as vector where every word is one dimension. That leads to even larger and sparser matrices but works anyhow.
You can look at [this](https://github.com/aleju/CharVectorizer) example on GitHub how strings can be coded (not my work).